# sed command is not working in shell script when a variable is passed as parameter

Tags: shell, sed

I have following codes in my shell script

```
a=$(cat php1.php | grep 'hello')
echo $a
sed -i 's/'"$a"'/world/' php1.php
```

The variable is getting printed correctly. However when i pass it as parameter to sed command, sed command is not working.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Edit last line to `echo sed -i 's/'"$a"'/world/' php1.php` and post output ... maybe `$a` contains a slash?

Comment: Every line of your code snippet is wrong in some way so you might want to post more of your full script to get feedback before you try to run it on your real file system.

Answer (score 2):

Your command works perfectly:

```
sed -i 's/'"$a"'/world/' php1.php
```

However, your `sed` command can use double quotes to expand shell variables automatically. Try this instead:

```
sed -i "s/$a/world/" php1.php
```

---

I may not completely understand what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're trying to replace `hello` with `world` (in a rather round-a-bout-way) it looks like you may want to add the `-o` flag to your `grep` command:

```
a=$(grep -o "hello" php1.php)
```

Comment: I know when given as command it works fine. However it is not working in script.I want to edit my config files and this is just a example that i posted and not the exact one.I tried with double quotes too but in vain.

Comment: It sounds as though the problem is unrelated to `sed`. I could speculate, but it would be quicker (and easier) if you could post the script you're having problems with as well as the contents of your php file. Perhaps I could help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of $a. I think $a contained some spacial characters.

Comment: I checked that also.It doesnt have special character.I think mistake lies in separator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the intent of your script is to replace all lines in php1.php that contain the word "hello" with the word "world". That'd just be this:

```
sed -i 's/.*hello.*/world/' php1.php
```

If you're trying to do something else, let us know what it is and we can help you.